# how add new line with content to form

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have short form with few positions. I want to add a functionality that will allow adding next item in the form when some body click button. I resolved problem adding new div with content (button, input and dropdown list select in one line) by jquery but I have problem with the position of the new div and content in that div (is not in on line). Next problem is deleting new div. For now I have something like this.

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="card-body lista-przyborow-test">
  <form method="POST" action="test.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" onsubmit="return confirm(&#039;sure?&#039;);" id="testt"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="fv9Xo9B0TIaDGlXmwGpzeE60e8VUDYIlKdXiOkx2">
   
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="rachunek" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Number:</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="rachunek" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm  " name="rachunek" value="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="data" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Data zakupu:</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="data" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm  " name="data" value="">
      </div>     
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group row" id="listap">
      <label for="status" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Equipemnt:</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <select name="artbiur" id="artbiur" class="form-control form-control-sm ">
            <option value="">Take equip</option>
            <option value="1">
              PAPER A4
            </option>
            <option value="2">
              PAPER A3
            </option>
            <option value="3">
              PEN
            </option>
            <option value="4">
              PENCIL
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">How many</label>
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          </div>
          <input id="ile" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm " name="ile" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="ile" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"></label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" id="dodaj-pozyc" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm">ADD NEXT POSITION</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
          SAVE
        </button>     
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </form>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $('#dodaj-pozyc').click(function() { 
    $('#listap').append(
      '<button type="button" style="width:70px" name="remove' + i + '" id="' + i + '" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-sm-center btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm btn_remove font-weight-bold">X</button>' +
      '<div class="col-md-6" id="lista-p-"' + i + '">' +
      '<div class="form-check form-check-inline">' +
      '<select name="artbiur" id="atrybut-nazwa-' + i + '" class="form-control form-control-sm ">' +
      '<option value="">Wybierz artykuł</option>' +

      ' <option value="1">' +
      'abcd' +
      '</option>' +

      '</select>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-check form-check-inline">' +
      '<label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Ilość:</label>' +
      '<div class="form-check form-check-inline">' +
      '<div class="form-check form-check-inline">' +
      '</div>' +
      '<input id="atrybut-ile-' + i + '" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm " name="ile" />' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>');
    i++;
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('input[name="remove"]' + id).remove();
    $('#atrybut-ile-' + id + '').remove();
    $('#atrybut-nazwa-' + id+  '').remove();
    $('#lista-p-' + id).empty();
    $('#lista-p-' + id).html("");
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Louys (thanks!) have added bootstrap styling and everything is now on one line as requested. I've added a disabled button to the original row just so that it looks a bit neater (this isn't necessary but a preference).

The delete button now works by moving up the DOM tree using `.closest` until it finds the new `div` with the wrapper class `.equipment-entry` and deletes the entire `div` and all it's children.

You should be able to adapt this to your needs.

---

```js
var i = 1;

// Click event for remove button
$(document).on("click", ".btn_remove", function() {

  // Move up DOM tree to nearest .wrapper and remove it all
  $(this).closest(".equipment-entry").remove();

});


// Original add code
// Added a wrapper div to make it easier to remove
$('#dodaj-pozyc').click(function() {
  $('#listap').append(
  
  // Added wrapper class .equipment-entry
       '<div class="col-md-6 equipment-entry">' +
        '<button type="button" style="width:70px" name="remove' + i + '" id="' + i + '" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-sm-center btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm btn_remove font-weight-bold">X</button>' +
          '<div class="form-check form-check-inline">' +
            '<select name="artbiur" id="artbiur" class="form-control form-control-sm ">' +
              '<option value="">Take equip</option>' +
              '<option value="1">' +
                'abcd' +
              '</option>' +
            '</select>' +
          '</div>' +
         '<div class="form-check form-check-inline">' +
            '<label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">How many</label>' +
            '<div class="form-check form-check-inline">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<input id="ile" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm " name="ile" />' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>');

  // Increase index
  i++;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

<html>

<body>
  <div class="card-body lista-przyborow-test">
    <form method="POST" action="test.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" onsubmit="return confirm(&#039;sure?&#039;);" id="testt"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="fv9Xo9B0TIaDGlXmwGpzeE60e8VUDYIlKdXiOkx2">

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="rachunek" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Number:</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input id="rachunek" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm  " name="rachunek" value="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="data" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Data zakupu:</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input id="data" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm  " name="data" value="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row" id="listap">
        <label for="status" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Equipment:</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        
           <button type="button" style="width:70px" name="remove' + i + '" id="' + i + '"  disabled="disabled" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-sm-center btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm btn_remove font-weight-bold">X</button>

          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <select name="artbiur" id="artbiur" class="form-control form-control-sm ">
              <option value="">Take equip</option>
              <option value="1">
                PAPER A4
              </option>
              <option value="2">
                PAPER A3
              </option>
              <option value="3">
                PEN
              </option>
              <option value="4">
                PENCIL
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">How many</label>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            </div>
            <input id="ile" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm " name="ile" />
          </div>
        </div>
        
 
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="ile" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"></label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <button type="button" id="dodaj-pozyc" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm">ADD NEXT POSITION</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
          SAVE
        </button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The CSS possibly only is bootstrap. ;)

Comment: sorry for my inadvertence. CSS is only bootstrap

Comment: Ha! Thank you Louys. Updated with bootstrap styling.

Comment: Is it possible to take the "btn-remove" from div "equipment-entry" and ad before it? Right know it add two div "equipment-entry" in one line.